# What is mean digest in computer terminology?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, terminology

I have some sentence [on this webpage](http://asprain.cn/ECMA2015/p894.htm), it sounds like:

> Its fields contain **digested** information about the names that are imported by the module and its concrete methods **use this digest to link**, instantiate, and evaluate the module.

What does mean `digested` or `use this digest to link`?

Comment: Have you researched the meaning of **digest** in dictionaries, as a noun? That may help you understand the analogy of digested information that has been "chewed over".

Comment: @WeatherVane maybe digest means like a "short adapted text of any texts"

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't asking for a meaning - I already know what a "digest" is. It is you who was asking what it means, and some kind soul below has opened the dictionary for you.

Comment: @WeatherVane You were the first to comment on my question. I here and proposed the meaning of which I thought. This is not the answer to you.

Answer (score 6):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/digest) defines a digest as

> a short written report providing the most important parts of a larger piece of writing, or one containing recent news

The best known example in everyday use is the [Reader's Digest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reader%27s_Digest), a magazine that originally contained abridged articles from various other publications.

In computer terms, a digest is made by condensing a document, message, keyword or other data item into a very short fixed-length summary, for example [CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) (typically 32 bits)  MD5 (128 bits) or [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) (160 bits). Note that [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is an abbreviation for Message **Digest** 5.

A digest can be used in many ways, for example to verify the integrity of a transmitted document, in cryptography and to generate a unique identifier for an item. In the document that you quote, it seems that the digest is being used as a unique identifier. [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (Universally Unique Identifiers) can be produced and used in this way.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to find the etymology of MD5 and thought searching for the meaning of "digest" in a CS context would help. I greatly appreciate how clear and well explained your answer is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a native English speaker and a computer programmer, and I have *no idea* what is meant by either "digested" or "digest" (noun) in that sentence, not even when examined in its original context.

The verb "digest", which refers to what the body does to food, can mean by analogy breaking something down into its constituent parts: a big thing broken into smaller things.

The noun "digest" most typically means a compilation of many texts into a larger collection: many small things fused into a bigger thing.

Note these two senses are precisely opposite.

The sense I am most familiar with of "digest" in computer terminology is  the noun pertaining to email discussion forums: an option where subscribers receive not individual emails one by one, but one big email, a "digest", containing all the messages of a time unit.

It is possible to verbify the noun sense and use "digest" as a verb to mean "make a digest (noun)".

I have no idea which of these senses pertain to the example you give.

Comment: If you are a programmer, you should know what MD5 is. It is an example of a digest, hence the name (Message Digest 5). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5. "many small things fused into a bigger thing." this is wrong. Digests are always smaller than the original document.

Comment: @JavaLatte Ah!  I do know what MD5 is, but never saw the acronym expanded.  "'many small things fused into a bigger thing.' this is wrong. Digests are always smaller than the original document." - obviously false, both from the example I already gave (email digests) and all the previous-to-CS examples such as a dictionary gives, e.g. legal digests, the magazine "Reader's Digest".

Comment: I accept your point about email digests.  That is actually documented here: http://www.yourdictionary.com/digest. Note that the definition of a legal digest from the same source contains the words "A book or series in which cases are **summarized**" and this text from the Readers Digest wiki page that I provided a link to: "usually **condensed** from a published book"